# Apache directive overwritten

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is a bit weird. I have setup the following .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # Rewrite short asset URLs
    RewriteRule ^(css|js|img|fonts)/(.*)$ /static/assets/$1/$2 [L]

    # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URI
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

So static assets are directly served to the client without being routed through the CMS. I have the exact same directives working on other sites.
But here, everything is still rewritten to index.php and returns a 404 error. *When I comment out the index.php-directive though, it works.*

This is what I would expect if the "`[L]`ast Rule" flag would be missing, but obviously, it is present. I also tried rules without regular expressions, added and removed flags or slashes, changed the position... Honestly, this is a bit embarrassing to ask, but I don't have any ideas anymore at this point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite short asset URLs
RewriteRule ^(css|js|img|fonts)/(.*)$ static/assets/$1/$2 [L,NC]

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URI
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Well.. it works now... but.. why?! Sorry. More precisely: What does the `^ -` do?

Comment: That rule actually ignored all the rules below for a request that is for a file or a directory.